# Vaadin BeanFieldGroup - "Property is not cascaded" when binding nested property

Tags: java, vaadin

I've been searching for hours on here and on the Vaadin forums, but I seem to have a unique problem here.

I simplified my problem a lot to be able to illustrate it easily.
So I have a Bean class:

```
public class Bean {
    private String name;
    private NestedBean nestedBean;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NestedBean getNestedBean() {
        return nestedBean;
    }

    public void setNestedBean(NestedBean nestedBean) {
        this.nestedBean = nestedBean;
    }

    Bean() {
        this.name = "Bean";
        this.nestedBean = new NestedBean();
    }
}
```

And its nested field, class NestedBean:

```
public class NestedBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    NestedBean() {
        this.name = "NestedBean";
    }
}
```

So now I want to bind an instance of Bean to two TextFields, with the help of a BeanFieldGroup:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();

BeanFieldGroup<Bean> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(Bean.class);
binder.setItemDataSource(bean);

addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Name", "name"));
addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Nested name", "nestedBean.name"));
```

This, however, throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property com.reygok.vaadin.main.Bean.nestedBean is not cascaded

Caused by: org.apache.bval.jsr.UnknownPropertyException: Property com.reygok.vaadin.main.Bean.nestedBean is not cascaded
```

I tried different solutions, like:

Creating the TextFields first and then using

```
binder.bind(textField, "nestedBean.name");
```

Doing this first:

```
binder.getItemDataSource().addNestedProperty("nestedBean.name");
```

But nothing changed the Exception. So does someone know what causes this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, so if others have the same problem:

The solution is to add the @Valid annotation to the fields that have nested fields inside of them.

So in my example:

```
public class Bean {
   private String name;

   @Valid
   private NestedBean nestedBean;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to bind member before setting bean data source

```
BeanFieldGroup<Bean> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(Bean.class);

// first
addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Name", "name"));
addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Nested name", "nestedBean.name"));
// then
binder.setItemDataSource(bean);
```

Comment: I tried that, too, but it didn't change anything. Why would this make a difference?